# Mismatched unique constraint

Tags: cassandra

Why I get this message:

```
mismatched input 'UNIQUE' expecting ')' (...KEY (user_id),CONSTRAINT email_uq [UNIQUE]...)
```

I want to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_id (user_id uuid, email text, password text, username text, user_info frozen<user_information>, user_since timestamp, PRIMARY KEY (user_id),CONSTRAINT email_uq UNIQUE (email));
```

Comment: Yep, not valid syntax in CQL.  Although primary keys are unique by default in Cassandra.  Switching the order of email and userid in the PK definition would enforce uniqueness on email.  The real question, is do you query by userid or by email more often.

Comment: But I have 2 tables users_by_email and users_by_id is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONSTRAINT` is not supported by CQL and Cassandra. Applications have to take care of any constraint which you want to have. Below query will work fine

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_id (user_id uuid,\
 email text,\
 password text,\
 username text,\
 user_info frozen<user_information>,\
 user_since timestamp,\
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id));
```